# (nuxt sequelize-typescript) Error:Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')

Tags: nuxt.js, sequelize-typescript

## Issue

when the models are added, the error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')` happens.

### Versions

- sequelize:6.19.0
- sequelize-typescript:2.1.3
- typescript:

below is the content of package.json

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "nuxt": "^2.15.8",
    "pg": "^8.7.3",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.4",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "sequelize": "^6.19.0",
    "sequelize-typescript": "^2.1.3",
    "vue": "^2.6.14",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxt/types": "^2.15.8",
    "@nuxt/typescript-build": "^2.1.0",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.24",
    "@types/validator": "^13.7.2",
    "sequelize-cli": "^6.4.1"
  }
}
```

### Actual behavior

the error happens when `sequelize.addModels()` is executed.
I attached the error message just after the related code.

### Expected behavior

the error does not happen and models can be added.

### Steps to reproduce

create `companyMaster.ts` like the code.
import `companyMaster.ts` in `index.ts` .
execute `index.ts` .

I referenced [the link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-typescript) about how to add models.

### Related code

commons/sequelize/models/companyMaster.ts

```js
import { Table, Column, Model } from 'sequelize-typescript';

@Table({
  schema: 'public',
  tableName: 'company_master',
  underscored: true,
  timestamps: true,
})
export class CompanyMaster extends Model {
  @Column
  companyNumber!: string;

  @Column
  companyName!: string;

  @Column
  homepageUrl!: string;
}
```

index.ts

```js
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize-typescript';
import { CompanyMaster } from './commons/sequelize/models/companyMaster';

const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DB_CONNECTION_URI || '', {
  models: [__dirname + '/commons/sequelize/models'], // (edited) here also the error happens.
});
sequelize.addModels([CompanyMaster]); // the error happens here
```

the error message for the line `sequelize.addModels([CompanyMaster]);`

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')

  at node_modules/sequelize-typescript/dist/sequelize/sequelize/sequelize.js:62:71
  at Array.map (<anonymous>)
  at Sequelize.defineModels (node_modules/sequelize-typescript/dist/sequelize/sequelize/sequelize.js:61:23)
  at Sequelize.addModels (node_modules/sequelize-typescript/dist/sequelize/sequelize/sequelize.js:37:36)
  at server/index.ts:30:15
  at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
  at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

(edited) the error message for the line `models: [__dirname + '/commons/sequelize/models'],`

```
Cannot find module 'commons/sequelize/models/companyMaster'

Require stack:
  - node_modules/sequelize-typescript/dist/sequelize/sequelize/sequelize-service.js
  - node_modules/sequelize-typescript/dist/sequelize/sequelize/sequelize.js
  - node_modules/sequelize-typescript/dist/index.js
  - server/index.ts

  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node_modules/module-alias/index.js:49:29)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
  at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
  at node_modules/sequelize-typescript/dist/sequelize/sequelize/sequelize-service.js:45:32
  at Array.map (<anonymous>)
  at node_modules/sequelize-typescript/dist/sequelize/sequelize/sequelize-service.js:43:18
  at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
  at getModels (node_modules/sequelize-typescript/dist/sequelize/sequelize/sequelize-service.js:35:20)
  at Sequelize.addModels (node_modules/sequelize-typescript/dist/sequelize/sequelize/sequelize.js:36:58)
  at new Sequelize (node_modules/sequelize-typescript/dist/sequelize/sequelize/sequelize.js:20:22)
  at server/index.ts:24:23
  at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
  at next (node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
  at Route.dispatch (node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
```

Comment: @seldesjo, please do not do suppelfluious edits

Answer (score 0):

If you will use the "models" options, you have to export the instance (CompanyMaster) class as default.

And this line:

```js
models: [__dirname + '/commons/sequelize/models']
```

Must be:

```js
models: [__dirname + "/commons/sequelize/models/*.ts"]
```

Also, you don't need ".addModels()"